# Living quarters limit in Fallout Shelter

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-shelter

It says my living quarters limit was reached but I only have 184 dwellers. What's the maximum amount of dwellers you can have? I'm trying to get my vault to go all the way to the bottom.

Answer (score 2):

This only means you need to build more Living quarters and upgrade them to house more dwellers.

You can have up to 200 dwellers.

http://uk.ign.com/wikis/fallout-shelter/Living_Quarters

Comment: Yes, still there's a bit room for OP to expand, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can have up to **200** [vault dwellers](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_dwellers_(Fallout_Shelter)). If you've hit your current cap, but haven't reached 200, you need to build additional [Living Quarters](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Living_quarters_(Fallout_Shelter)) or upgrade the ones you have.

Answer (score 0):

There's a related problem that I think the question was about.  Once you have enough living space for 200 dwellers, you can no longer build any more living quarters.  Even if you have fewer than 200 dwellers. If you have too many dwellers you can not destroy any living quarters either.  So you're essentially stuck with the quarters where they are permanently unless you're willing to evict residents.

It puts some restrictions on trying to remodel the shelter.